# Styling JTableHeader to remove extra whitespace

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I'm attempting to style a JTable to match a "Dark theme", but I can't seem to find out how to remove a small white space at the end of the table header:

faulty table:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll9Fs.png]

I've looked set the following UI keys on the Table Header:

```
UIManager.put("TableHeader.font", theme.getPrimaryFont().deriveFont(16f));
UIManager.put("TableHeader.foreground", theme.getEnabledTextColor());
UIManager.put("TableHeader.background", theme.getPrimaryColor());
```

and the following UI keys on the Table:

```
UIManager.put("Table.font", theme.getSecondaryFont());
UIManager.put("Table.foreground", theme.getEnabledTextColor());
UIManager.put("Table.background", theme.getPrimaryColor());
UIManager.put("Table.selectionBackground", theme.getSecondaryColor());
UIManager.put("Table.selectionForeground", theme.getEnabledTextColor());
UIManager.put("Table.gridColor", theme.getPrimaryColor());
UIManager.put("Table.scrollPaneBorder", new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
UIManager.put("Table.focusCellHighlightBorder", border);
UIManager.put("Table.cellNoFocusBorder", eb);
```

There's also a custom TableUI that inherits from BasicTableUI. I'm extending the MetalLookAndFeel class as well.

I have tried removed custom scroll bar UI, removing the custom Table UI, and overriding paint methods but the little white sliver still persists.
How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Post your [MCVE] demonstrating the problem. The `MCVE` should just be the frame with a table added to it. And you don't need custom data, just add a DefaultTableModel to it with a few rows/columns.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be controlled by the TableColumnModel and the columnWidth properties